# How to manage SQL Server Always Encrypted Keys schema in a Visual Studio Database project

Tags: azure, sql-server-data-tools, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

I have a SQL Server 2016 database using Always Encrypted with Azure Key Vault to encrypt some of the columns. I would like to replace the `KEY_PATH` and `ENCRYPTED_VALUE` properties with environment specific values during deployment.  How could this be managed within a Visual Studio Database Project?

```
CREATE COLUMN MASTER KEY [CMK_Test]
WITH (
     KEY_STORE_PROVIDER_NAME = N'AZURE_KEY_VAULT',
     KEY_PATH = N'[Value]'
);

CREATE COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY [CEK_TestColumn]
WITH VALUES
(
     COLUMN_MASTER_KEY = [CMK_Test],
     ALGORITHM = N'RSA_OAEP',
     ENCRYPTED_VALUE = [Value]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable on KEY_PATH but not on ENCRYPTED_VALUE

```
CREATE COLUMN MASTER KEY [CMK_SSO]
WITH (
     KEY_STORE_PROVIDER_NAME = N'AZURE_KEY_VAULT',
     KEY_PATH = N'$(ColumnMasterKey_Path)'
);
```

Declare a variable on project properties.
[image]